# React Native project - cannot make API calls with AwsAmplify through custom library

Tags: react-native, authentication, package, aws-amplify

I have a react-native app (without expo) called myapp.

I have a private custom package called myapp-core, where I handle AwsAmplify services (Auth, Storage) -  to do login/signOut/etc.

I want to use myapp-core in myapp project, so I added it as a dependency in `package.json` (`"myapp-core": "file:../myapp-core",`) and then `yarn install`.

The problem I’m facing is that when I call `myapp-core.authService.login(username, password)` from the mobile project, I catch the error:

> “ { “line”:177826, “column”: 17, “sourceURL”:
>   “http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false”
>   } ”

From my research, that means my custom library cannot make api calls - but I don’t know exactly.

When I use aws-amplify's Auth object directly in my mobile project, it works.

Hopefully relevant code:

```
/**=============================**/
/** myapp/CoreServices.js **/

import { AmplifyService } from “myapp-core";

export default class CoreServices {

 constructor() {

    AmplifyService.configure();
    const auth = AmplifyService.authService();

    auth
      .login(“myusername”, “mypassword”)
      .then(user => console.warn("success", user))
      .catch(error => console.warn("error", error));
  }
}


/**=============================**/
/** myapp-core/AmplifySevice.js **/

import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import AuthService from '../AuthService/AuthService';
import awsConfigs from '../aws-exports';

class AmplifyService {

  static authServiceInstance = null;
  static storageServiceInstance = null;

  static configure(config = awsConfigs) {
    if (config === null || config === undefined) {
      throw new Error('AmplifyService must be initialized with Auth and Storage configurations.');
    }
    Amplify.configure({
      Auth: { /*...*/ },
      Storage: { /*...*/ }
    });
  }

  static authService() {
    if (!this.authServiceInstance) {
      this.authServiceInstance = new AuthService();
    }
    return this.authServiceInstance;
  }

  static storageService() {
    console.warn('storage service');
    //  initialize storage service
    //  return storage service
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my project's issue.
Maybe someone will benefit from my solution.

The problem didn't have anything to do with AwsAmplify, but with the way I linked the projects: `myapp-core` with `myapp`.

The issue was that in the `myapp-core` I am using the `aws-amplify` package that I would normally link to the mobile projects (`react-native link`) but in my case I assumed (wrongly) that it wouldn't be the case.

The solution was to link whatever packages were needed in the iOS/Android projects to install the proper pods/gradle libraries, like `react-native link amazon-cognito-identity-js` for authentication.

... and now I am finally happy :))

Links that shed some light:

- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1492
- https://eshlox.net/2018/11/12/aws-amplify-react-native-typeerror-cannot-read-property-computemodpow-of-undefined/

In case somebody thinks this isn't the solution and I got lucky or something, please comment or post another response.